# help with investigating the uniformly convergence of a function sequence.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I have to check the uniform convergence of the below mentioned function sequence:
$f_n(x) = \frac{1-\ln x}{nx}$
while $0<x<1$

at the answers, it's told that the sequence doesn't converge uniformly - but somehow I receive that it **does** uniformly converge.

I looked for the maximum of the function and received the max point equals $e^2$.
when I look for the value of $\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(e^2)$ , it equals 0 - meaning it does converge. (in cotradiction to the answers)

what am I doing wrong?
thanks.

Comment: On which set shall the convergence be examined?

Comment: Daniel - x is between 0 and 1 (0,1 not included)

Comment: What is $\lim\limits_{x\downarrow 0} f_n(x)$?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: @Ami, $\lim_{x\to+0} f_n(x)=+\infty$, but $f_n(1)=1/n\to 0$.

Comment: I mean that looking at that limit should show you that the convergence is not uniform. Additionally, $e^2$ does not belong to the domain to be considered. (And $f_n$ has no maximum but a minimum.)

Comment: If I understand correctly, when I look at x->0 it would be: ${\infty\over 0*\infty}$
so I can't understand how I can suppose it still reaches +$\infty$ as @MichaelGaluza says?

Comment: @Ami, you may use l'Hopital rule ($n$ is fixed)

Comment: @MichaelGaluza excuse me but I really can't get why.. lopital is when its ${\infty}\over{\infty}$ or ${0}\over{0}$.. here it's ${\infty}\over{0*\infty}$.

Comment: @Ami, my bad. $-\ln x\to+\infty$, $x\to 0$; hence, $(1-\ln x)/x = \infty/0 = \infty$.

Comment: @MichaelGaluza denominator is x*n while $x\to0$,$n\to\infty$, so it can't be 0...

Comment: @Ami For each fixed $n$, we look at what happens when $x$ approaches $0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer so I treat $n$ as a constant? If it's ok- I will appreciate a lot some short logical proof of this exercise

Comment: You treat it as a constant temporarily, while looking at $\lim\limits_{x\downarrow 0} f_n(x)$. After that, you can think about what happens when $n\to\infty$.